# How to install Tally.Server 9

Tags: server, software-installation

I need to install Tally.Server 9 on a Ubuntu 12 server.

Tally is a accounting software and a multi user application where the main application is installed on the server and users have the client side version installed in the users PC.

Answer (score 2):

you can install it through wine. Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

after installing wine.

You should have downloaded the .exe Tally software .

Now right click on that TallySoftware.exe  and choose install with wine if you have GUI.

If you dont have GUI you can do it from command line as

```
wine /path/to/tallysoftware.exe
```

Then it will install. Hope that helps.