# How do I install Tally in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, windows, software-recommendation, finance

I use 18.04 on my HP laptop. Is it possible to install Tally software on it for accounting purpose ? If no, is there any alternative that works on Ubuntu?

Comment: you will have to use Wine. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/391926/796752)

Comment: @Jrct will it work for desktop version as well ? pomsky, It is a very popular accounting software

Comment: Then consider providing reference / description / link to the software, "popular" is quite a problematic term. It sounds to me (from @jrct's comment) it's not software for Ubuntu or Linux in general, so there is a big chance Ubuntu users won't know of it.

Comment: @user227495 I haven't personally tried it. I dont think there is an official Linux port

Comment: @pomsky Tally is a proprietary accounting software for Windows

Comment: Sorry, I believe my previous comment was quite unclear. What I meant is since you're also asking for an alternative-recommendation, a couple of things need to be added to question: 1. the **purpose** of the software, 2. your minimum **requirements** for it (refer to the [software-recommendation] tag [info](https://askubuntu.com/tags/software-recommendation/info)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install tally on ubuntu. I too was facing the problem. Here, I will tell you what to do.

1. Install wine (wine is used to install windows software on Linux O/S)
2. Download tally executable file (.exe) file from the internet.
3. Then open terminal and type wine nameOfTallyExecutableFile.exe and hit enter
   and then you are good to go.

   **NOTE :**
   ~ if you are trying to install it using wine command and it shows error that it cannot find the file then here is what you need to do. remove the spaces that are present in the .exe file name e.g if it is Tally Erp .exe you have to change it to tallyerp.exe or just rename it to tally.exe 
   ~ Second error that I Encounter was it was showing me 
    **Out of memory 
    Use native 64 bit null**,
    Here is what to do, you just need to connect your pc to internet and run the file again it will run.